# User cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method, HILT

Tags: kotlin, dagger-2, dagger-hilt

I'm using Dagger Hilt in an application and I have this module:

```
@InstallIn(ActivityComponent::class)
@Module
object MainActivityModule {

    /**
        Provides current user that is stored in an intent after Logged In
    **/
    @Provides
    @CurrentUser
    fun providesCurrentUser(
        @ActivityContext activity: Context
    ): User {
        val intent: Intent = (activity as MainActivity).intent

        return intent.getSerializableExtra(CURRENT_USER) as User
    }
}
```

Then I try to call the `User` in another module like this:

```
@InstallIn(ViewModelComponent::class)
@Module
object RepositoryModule {
    
    @Provides
    fun providesActivityRepository(

    @CurrentUser currentUser: User

    ): ActivityRepository {
        return ActivityRepository(currentUser)
    }
}
```

I get an error: `User cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method.`

I'm new to hilt dagger, any idea what I'm doing wrong?

I tried to change `@InstallIn(ViewModelComponent::class)` to `@InstallIn(ActivityComponent::class)` but the same

Answer (score 1):

As in the [Hilt Component hierarchy](https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-android#component-hierarchy), ViewModelComponent is a subcomponent of ActivityRetainedComponent, which is a subcomponent of SingletonComponent. ("`ActivityRetainedComponent` lives across configuration changes, so it is created at the first `Activity#onCreate()` and destroyed at the last `Activity#onDestroy()`.") Consequently, your `RepositoryModule` should be installed in `ActivityComponent` or `ActivityRetainedComponent` if you'd like it to be accessible from the `MainActivityModule` you installed in `ActivityComponent`.

Since you mentioned "I tried to change `@InstallIn(ViewModelComponent::class)` to `@InstallIn(ActivityComponent::class)` but the same", I recommend posting the full and exact error message: Your message `User cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method` might indicate that elsewhere you are trying to inject `User` and not the qualified `@CurrentUser User` you've posted here.

Comment: Hello thank you for your response, in fact, I would like `MainActivityModule`  to be accessible into `RepositoryModule`. Let say for example that the user is logged in then I'm passing this object into an intent. To call this intent in the `MainActivityModule` I need a "context", the context is callable only in the `ActivityComponent`. I don't know if I'm clear. Anyway the information provided by you is very valuable.